# make clickable areas of layout background image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, clickable

i use `LinearLayout` and set background for my layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back">
```

and back image is:
[image]

As shown in background image i design some place of button, and now i want to make clickable that areas, what can i do? thnx

Answer (score 0):

This maybe doesn't answer your question but I have a suggestion:

Why don't you just set the background to blue and then place Buttons to your layout (maybe you need to think of using a TableLayout instead)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the windowManager to do that but I think it's better done as Thanos said.

```
//get the instance of WindowManager
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                 <WIDTH OF THE BUTTON>,
                 <HEIGHT OF THE BUTTON>,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH|
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                 PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    //make sure (0;0) is in the top left corner
         params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
     params.x = <POSITION X OF THE BUTTON>
     params.y = <POSITION Y OF THE BUTTON>
//make an empty layout so you can get the click event
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this/*or your context here*/);
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //do stuff
            }
        });
windowManager.addView(layout, params);
```

if you want to see the shape of the clickable area you can add a view that match it's parent's size in the layout